# Sorting Strings with 2 keys

Tags: java, string, sorting

So, I need to sort Strings based on two keys in Java.

I get raw text input containing names, like so: `city_name person_name`.

The goal is to primarily sort the cities alfabetically, and secondary the person names. Then it needs to show how many people with that speific name live in that city.

So, with input as:

```
C Zeke
A John
C Pete
B Lisa
A John
B John
C Pete
C Pete
B Lisa
```

it needs to output

```
A John 2
B John 1
B Lisa 2
C Pete 3
C Zeke 1
```

This has left me absolutely dumbfounded. Any ideas?

Comment: Are your classes implementing the Comparable interface? If so, then simply code the compareTo method to first compare data held by the primary key field, and if they are equal (and *only* if the two primary key fields are equal) compare the secondary key field. That's it.

Comment: "This question shows research effort; it is usefull and clear". No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just edited according to comments. MultiKeyMap is not part of the JDK :(.

You could use a `MultiKeyMap` or a `Map<String,Integer>` and store the city and the name as keys, and the number of encounters as a value. Then you would just iterate through the map's entries and print the values

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

for ( String cityAndName : input ) { 
   String city = // split and get city
   String name = // split and get name
   Integer noOfEncounters = 0;
   if ( map.containsKey(city+"_"+name) ) { 
        noOfEncounters = map.get(city+"_"+name);
        noOfEncounters++;
   }
   map.put(city+"_"+name,noOfEncounters);
}
```

Even better would be if you have an object which wrapps city and name. Something like Person. Then you would just override the hashcode and equals method to be calculated against the `city` and `name` attributes, and you need not do that ugly concatenation.

Comment: That is not part of the JDK.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out. Turned out I was just being an idiot and thinking way too hard.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you have a class `Person` that contains `person_name` and `city_name`, just put them into a `List` and sort them using `Collections.sort(List, Comparator)` using a custom `Comparator` implementation that first checks for the city and then for the name:

```
Collections.sort(people, new Comparator<Person>() {
    compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
        int c = p1.getCity().compareTo(p2.getCity());
        return (c == 0) ? p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName()) : c;
    }
});
```

Note that you might have to add `null` checks. Also think of comparing the strings via `compareToIgnoreCase` instead.